# What's the "right" way to ensure all of the autoref names are capitalized, in an sty?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, capitalization, autoref

Suppose I'm writing an `.sty` for people to use. This `.sty` might be loaded before or after `hyperref`, and possibly before some other packages define `\chaptername`, `\chapterautorefname`, `\sectionname` etc. to lowercase names (actually, they probably don't, but I want to be robust).

How should I enforce the capitalization of these names (i.e. for `\autoref{chap:foo}` to produce "Chapter 2" rather than "chapter 3")?

Comment: Define it as late as possible, but be prepared: any user will find a way to screw your plans.

Comment: How about "Don't use the `\autoref` machinery. Instead, (a) load the `cleveref` package and (b) base your own .sty file on the `\cref` and `\crefrange` macros. Be sure to load the `cleveref` package with the options `nameinlink` (to mimic the output of `\autoref`) and `capitalize` (`capitalise` "works too...). Finally, for good measure, issue the instruction `\let\autoref`\cref`.

Comment: @Mico: Could you flesh this out a bit with a concrete example and it an answer? I have some comments to make about it...

Comment: @einpoklum  - Done. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For a step up in robustness against user interference, I suggest you not employ the `\autoref` machinery. Instead, I suggest you work with the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package and its user-level macro `\cref`.

Something along the following lines, maybe. First, create a `.sty` file called, say, `myrefs.sty`.

```
\ProvidesPackage{myrefs}[2019/05/31 einpoklum's helper style file]
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} % or whatever options are needed

\RequirePackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % 'nameinlink' to mimic \autoref's behavior
%% Use low-level controls to hard-code the required appearance.
\crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}
\crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
% etc

\let\autoref\cref % set \autoref as an alias for \cref
\endinput
```

Then, load the style file in the preamble of your tex file and use either `\autoref` or `\cref` to create cross-references. Of course, you should still advise the users of your package to (a) *not* load the `hyperref` package and (b) load the `myrefs` package *last*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{myrefs}
\begin{document}
\chapter{AAA} \label{chap:aaa}
\section{BBB} \label{sec:bbb}
\begin{equation}1+1=2\label{eq:triv}\end{equation}
Cross-references to \autoref{chap:aaa,sec:bbb,eq:triv}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. How is this better than using autoref? People can just as easily change `\crefname`'s, cant they? 2. Won't it be confusing/cause trouble for authors, for me to sneekily replace their `\autoref` with a `\cref` 3. The `myrefs` package will probably not be loaded last.

Comment: @einpoklum - I deliberately call my solution a "step up in robustness" against user interference, not "the ultimate in robustness." Indeed, if somebody wants to sabotage the package, they can look inside the sty file and modify the `\crefname` macros to their hearts' content. Nevertheless, this solution is more robust than any solution that relies on the values of the LaTeX-kernel names. About the package loading order: Untoward things can happen if `hyperref` and `cleveref` aren't loaded last. However, that's no different from any other method that might use these packages.

Comment: I think this is a nice suggestion and have upvoted, but was reflecting how authors using my sty without being aware of the details may see things.